# When using python mox mock objects is there any way to avoid all of them being equal (as in __eq__)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mox, pymox

I'm experiencing some problems derived from the fact than several all mox Mock object of a given class seem to be equal in the `==`,`__eq__` sense although they are different objects (at least `mock1 is mock2` returns `False`). is there any way to prevent that behaviour?

In the code example below you can see that the count is wrong because it thinks all the mocks are equal:

```
import mox

class MyClass(object):
    pass

real1 = MyClass()
real2 = MyClass()
listreal = (real1, real2)
mocker = mox.Mox()
mock1 = mocker.CreateMock(MyClass)
mock2 = mocker.CreateMock(MyClass)
listmock = (mock1, mock2)

real1 == real2  # False
real1 is real2  # False
listreal.count(real1)  # 1
mock1 == mock2  # True
mock1 is mock2  # False
listmock.count(mock1)  # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the  implementation of `__eq__` for `mox.MockAnything` and `mox.MockObject` just compares the `replay_mode` and the `expected_calls_queue` so any mock object that is expecting the same calls is actually "equal".

```
class MockAnything:
  def __eq__(self, rhs):
    """Provide custom logic to compare objects."""

    return (isinstance(rhs, MockAnything) and
            self._replay_mode == rhs._replay_mode and
            self._expected_calls_queue == rhs._expected_calls_queue)
```

That has several implications when the mocks are used in collections for methods like `list.remove()`, etc.

You have to add some calls to a fake method to make the mocks not equal in the eyes of `__eq__`.